# Blazor webassembly: synchronize client and server time

Tags: api, time, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly app. My project contains an API (asp net core) and the Blazor WA app.
The project calculate the time it takes for a team to run a track.
I safe the start time in the API (server time) and I show the chronometer going on on the blazor app by doing currentTime (client time) - startTime (server time).
I tested everything home without any problem but with other devices, the client time is not synced with the server time so the chronometer began at 50 seconds.

What's the best and easiest solution? (I don't need the time to be perfect)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client is using an initial starting time to display a timer on the screen, then it needs to be accurate when the stopping time occurs as well. Why not have the client poll for an updated chronometer state once per second while the client is open? Every second the client gets from the server the start time, the elapsed time since, and the end time (if one exists).

Alternatively, you could do the same thing with SignalR if you want the stop pushed from the server and not from client polling (would save some bandwidth and make the timer more accurate at the cost of complexity in the page).

Comment: Can't do that because the chronometer can be started and stopped on any device.

Comment: Your initial post doesn't make it clear that the ongoing chronometer state is calculated on the server. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.ToUniversalTime()` of your `DateTime` object. You will have to send the converted date from the API and also need to convert the client's date. Then you will code something like this:

```
var elapsedTime = currentTime.ToUniversalTime() - startTime;
```

The startTime would be Universal Time already from the API.

Otherwise, you can also send your server's `Timezone` with your API response and convert the client's time according to that.

You can use this extension method as well:

```
public static DateTime ToTimezone(this DateTime dateTime, string timezone) //timezone="Hawaiian Standard Time"
{
    TimeZoneInfo timezoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, timezoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
}
```

Comment: I'm only using UtcNow so the TimeZone here is not the problem. It's more the fact that one device can be at 14h30 for example and the server at 14h32.